# Convert plain text URLs to HTML hyperlink in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a form in HTML, i ask the user to enter a url, once that happens it comes back in plain text in PHP. What i want to happen is that when they enter their URL and submit the link that they have entered will become clickable. This is the code i have. I hope this helps.

```
        <?php
             $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
             $course = $_POST['course'];
             $projecturl = $_POST['projecturl'];


             echo "<p>You are <span class='textblue'> $firstname</span> and ";
             echo "your course at the college is: <span class='textblue'> $course </span></p> ";
            echo "your project url is: <span class='textblue'> $projecturl</span></p> ";
           echo   "a href=’google.com’>Google</a>” .
                    ?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if i knew where i went wrong and how i am stuck for advice...?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to ask _specific_ questions here, not just go “I don’t know” or “I’m stuck”. Explain what _exactly_ your problem is! You know what the HTML code for a link should look like, right? (If not, then please _go inform_ yourself! This is not a place to teach the absolute basics.) And if you do know, then show us your _attempt_ to create that kind of HTML dynamically, with that URL you got contained in your variable.

Comment: Wording a question correctly can be difficult. As I read it you simply want a HTML link which uses the input from the user. Something like `echo '<a href="'.$url.'">the link</a>';`. That doesn't seem very difficult, given what you already have.

Comment: Correct, thats exactly what i want, and for it to be clickable instead of plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `parse_url`, for example:

```
<?php
$url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';
var_dump(parse_url($url));
?>
```

If you want to search more about this code:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Thankyou, i will look into the link you have sent. Could you tell me what needs to go in HTML along side this information if possible? I have been researching all night and its difficult to find information on this specifically.

Comment: On your form in HTML you have to put 'value ="<?php echo$variable_name ?>"'

Comment: like <input name="url" type="text" class="textbox" id="url" size="70" maxlength="50" value ="<?php echo $projecturl; ?>"/>

Comment: Yep, i have exactly that, but what i need is when its processed, instead of returning my link in plain text, it comes back as a hyperlink if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

change `echo statements` like this

```
echo "<p>You are <span class='textblue'>.'"$firstname"'.</span> and ";
```

Comment: Okay, i have done this.

Comment: This won't change anything, apart from putting quotes around the name.

Comment: I thought as much

Comment: Solve problem? @0011

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: please check you got values in your variables?